# How to improve this @keyframes animation and make it more smooth

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to create a keyframes animation which represents something has been sent by having a paper plane icon fly in and out of a circle.

*(I'm using the letter X instead of an icon for to reproduce it more easily)*

I have it almost working *(see below)* but find that it can be jumpy at times with the top part of the **X** flashing near the top of the circle.  It's particularly noticeable if you open the code snippet below in full screen.

[image]

Also, I'd like to have the animation seem more smooth with the **X** appearing outside the circle for less time.

Is there a way to fix this or do it in a better way?

---

http://jsfiddle.net/hp1new8L/38/

```css
.icon-send {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.icon-send:before {
    position: relative;
    content: 'x';
    line-height: 100px;
    animation-name: flying-paper-plane;
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }

@keyframes flying-paper-plane {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  49.9% {
    left: 60px;
    top: -60px;
  }

  50% {
    left: 0;
    top: -60px;
  }

  50.1% {
    left: -60px;
    top: 60px;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-send"></div>
```

Comment: try `cubic-bezier` timing function

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara thanks but unfortunately that does not stop it from being jumpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the plane invisible at 50%, you don't see it when it jumps to the other side (and looks a bit better IMO). For the timing you could use `cubic-bezier` as [@ChintuYadavSara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10330944/chintuyadavsara) suggested.

```css
.icon-send {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.icon-send:before {
    position: relative;
    content: 'x';
    line-height: 100px;
    animation-name: flying-paper-plane;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }

@keyframes flying-paper-plane {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  49.9% {
    left: 60px;
    top: -60px;
  }
  
  50% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity:0;
  }

  50.1% {
    left: -60px;
    top: 60px;
  }

  100% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-send"></div>
```